Python Implementation: Mountain Profile with Spline, Parametric Curve, and Bezier Curve
I have a project to implement in Python where I have to choose a mountain and implement one third of the code with spline, another third with parametric curve, and the last third with Bezier curve. However, the question arises: how do I divide an image into three thirds to plot a different function in each third? I attach what I have done so far, but my question is only about what I mentioned.
from google.colab import files
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# Fazer o upload da imagem
uploaded = files.upload()

# Nome do arquivo da imagem carregada
image_filename = 'Dedo_De_Deus_-_Vista_Teresopolis.jpg'

# Carregar a imagem
img = mpimg.imread(image_filename)

# Mostrar a imagem
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')  # Opcional: remove os eixos
plt.title('Imagem das montanhas')
plt.show()

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Convertendo a imagem para escala de cinza
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Aplicar limiarização para binarizar a imagem
_, img_thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 125, 300, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Mostrar a imagem binarizada
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.imshow(img_thresh, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Imagem binarizada das montanhas')
plt.axis('off')  # Opcional: remove os eixos
plt.show()

# Encontrar contornos
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Selecionar o maior contorno (pressupõe que é o contorno da montanha)
profile = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea).squeeze()

# Extrair coordenadas x e y do contorno
x = profile[:, 0]
y = profile[:, 1]

# Mostrar o perfil extraído
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.plot(x, y, 'r', label='Perfil extraído')
plt.title('Perfil das montanhas extraídas')
plt.axis('off')  # Opcional: remove os eixos
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Ordenar os pontos pelo eixo x
sorted_indices = np.argsort(x)
x = x[sorted_indices]
y = y[sorted_indices]

# Remover duplicatas em x
_, unique_indices = np.unique(x, return_index=True)
x = x[unique_indices]
y = y[unique_indices]

# Implementação manual da spline cúbica
class CubicSpline:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.n = len(x) - 1
        self.h = np.diff(x)
        self.alpha = [0] + [3 * (y[i + 1] - y[i]) / self.h[i] - 3 * (y[i] - y[i - 1]) / self.h[i - 1] for i in range(1, self.n)] + [0]
        self.l = np.ones(self.n + 1)
        self.mu = np.zeros(self.n + 1)
        self.z = np.zeros(self.n + 1)
        self.c = np.zeros(self.n + 1)
        self.b = np.zeros(self.n)
        self.d = np.zeros(self.n)

        # Forward elimination
        for i in range(1, self.n):
            self.l[i] = 2 * (self.x[i + 1] - self.x[i - 1]) - self.h[i - 1] * self.mu[i - 1]
            self.mu[i] = self.h[i] / self.l[i]
            self.z[i] = (self.alpha[i] - self.h[i - 1] * self.z[i - 1]) / self.l[i]

        # Back substitution
        for j in range(self.n - 1, -1, -1):
            self.c[j] = self.z[j] - self.mu[j] * self.c[j + 1]
            self.b[j] = (self.y[j + 1] - self.y[j]) / self.h[j] - self.h[j] * (self.c[j + 1] + 2 * self.c[j]) / 3
            self.d[j] = (self.c[j + 1] - self.c[j]) / (3 * self.h[j])

    def __call__(self, x_new):
        i = np.searchsorted(self.x, x_new) - 1
        i = np.clip(i, 0, self.n - 1)
        dx = x_new - self.x[i]
        return self.y[i] + self.b[i] * dx + self.c[i] * dx**2 + self.d[i] * dx**3

# Criar a spline cúbica
cs = CubicSpline(x, y)

# Gerar novos pontos para a curva spline
x_new = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
y_spline = cs(x_new)

# Mostrar a curva spline
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Pontos extraídos')
plt.plot(x_new, y_spline, 'lime', label='Spline cúbica')
plt.title('Spline cúbica ajustada ao perfil')
plt.axis('off')  # Opcional: remove os eixos
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Definir o parâmetro t
t = np.linspace(0, 1, len(x))

# Interpolar os pontos x e y em função de t
x_parametric = np.interp(t, t, x)
y_parametric = np.interp(t, t, y)

# Mostrar a curva paramétrica
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Pontos extraídos')
plt.plot(x_parametric, y_parametric, 'magenta', label='Curva paramétrica')
plt.title('Curva paramétrica ajustada ao perfil')
plt.axis('off')  # Opcional: remove os eixos
plt.legend()
plt.show()

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import comb

# Função para calcular a curva de Bézier
def bezier_curve(points, num_points=200):
    n = len(points) - 1
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, num_points)
    curve = np.zeros((num_points, 2))
    for i in range(num_points):
        for j in range(n + 1):
            curve[i] += comb(n, j) * (1 - t[i])**(n - j) * t[i]**j * points[j]
    return curve

# Selecionar pontos de controle do perfil extraído
num_control_points = 200  # Ajuste o número de pontos de controle conforme necessário
control_points_indices = np.linspace(0, len(x) - 1, num_control_points).astype(int)
control_points = np.array([x[control_points_indices], y[control_points_indices]]).T

# Gerar a curva de Bézier usando os pontos de controle
bezier_curve_points = bezier_curve(control_points)

# Mostrar a curva de Bézier
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Pontos extraídos')
plt.plot(bezier_curve_points[:, 0], bezier_curve_points[:, 1], 'aqua', label='Curva de Bézier')
plt.scatter(control_points[:, 0], control_points[:, 1], c='red', s=10, label='Pontos de controle', zorder=5)
plt.title('Curva de Bézier ajustada ao perfil')
plt.axis('off')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.plot(x_new, y_spline, 'lime', label='Spline cúbica')
plt.plot(x_parametric, y_parametric, 'magenta', label='Curva paramétrica')
plt.plot(bezier_curve_points[:, 0], bezier_curve_points[:, 1], 'aqua', label='Curva de Bézier')
plt.title('Curvas ajustadas ao perfil da montanha')
plt.axis('off')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

which gives
mountain with 3 plots
I defined the three functions and plotted them all overlapped because I don't know how to divide the image into three thirds, one for each function, and I couldn't find anything like that on the internet.

In vertical stripes seems like a reasonable way to do it for mountains.
